# Schema Field Translatable option not saving

Tags: schema, translation-manager

I have installed Translation Manager and configured my source and target Publications fine.

However, when I open a Schema (in Chrome) to update the fields' `Translatable` options I am not able to save the `true` value. I can, however, update anything else in the Schema and I can check the `Translatable` checkbox but when I save the Schema the `Translatable` checkbox sets back to unchecked.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could check, please?  This is SDL Web 8.5.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache and restarting the CM server?

Comment: Presumably on valid field types and at the root schema level 
- is there anything in the debug window between clicking save and the page refreshing?

Comment: Maybe an Event System interfering?